# How to use short Java property name in Powerdesigner?

Tags: java, powerdesigner

When using PowerDesigner to generate javaBean I got this preview,problem is  I don't know how to replace  the "java.lang.String" with "String" 
Preview Code:

```
   public java.lang.String userName;
```

Comment: In the list of datatypes, I have both String and java.lang.String. Why did you pick java.lang.String?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to do this.  I could not find one.

But if there was a way, it would be potentially dangerous.

Suppose that you created a class called `String` ... by hand ... and put it into the same package as your generated bean code.  If the PowerDesigner generator were to systematically replace all references to `java.lang.String` in the generated code with `String`, then it would mean different things depending on what was on the classpath at compile time.  It is an edge case ... but it is the kind of thing that would trip up PowerDesigner users, especially users with minimal Java skills.

By using full classnames, the PowerDesigner generator is avoiding this kind of problem.  And the flipside is that it should not matter.  Generally speaking you should not need to read the generated code.